# “Wasn’t it you” or “weren’t it you”?

Tags: grammar, dummy-pronouns

I have always said “Wasn’t it you who _______”; it feels the most natural. However, you use “were” or “are” with “you. Shouldn’t it then be “Weren’t it you”?

Comment: I think this topic is related to past subjunctive sentences. I think you may like reading about past subjunctives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We say *"Wasn't it you"* and not *"Weren't it you"* because the subject of the sentence is actually **it**, not **you**.  Think about how you would make the corresponding statement to this question: It **was** you who _____

**It** in this case is the actual grammatical subject of the sentence, not "you".  *It* here is an [anticipatory "it"](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Post-positive-Adjective.htm), which functions as kind of a dummy pronoun.  You could also say "You were the one who ____" but "It was you who ____" is a way of emphasizing the fact.

Comment: "were it not for my father, I wouldn't go to the university" I think this question has something to do with past subjunctive sentences, too. Or maybe I am wrong

Comment: @Cardinal - That's a good point.  In that case I think it is something to do with the subjunctive, but it's a great counterexample.